# Setting default password to airflow docker

Tags: docker, airflow

In order to setup an easy-to-deploy local airflow environment for testing purposes, I wanted to create a simple docker-compose file using the airflow docker image.

The resulting docker-compose is dead simple :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  airflow_init:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "airflow"
      MYSQL_USER: "airflow"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"

  airflow:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mysql+pymysql://airflow:password@db/airflow?charset=utf8mb4
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: airflow
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: airflow
    command: standalone
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I just had to create a Dockerfile to install some python dependencies. You can find the code here :

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest
RUN pip install --user --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user pymysql
```

Airflow start smoothly and setup the database. However, it seems to ignore the `_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME` and `_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD` environment variables. Thus, in order to connect to the WebUI, I still have to copy-paste the password provided in the terminal which is annoying.

What is the simplest and most straightforward way to provide a default admin user at startup? I found some solutions online but they all feel *hacky*

Kind regards

Comment: You should have a look at [How to use secrets in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/). You can also rely on runner, here's [Kubernetes doc about it](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Comment: @vdolez At this stage I don't really care about secrets as I am setting up the dev environment that will allow all developers on the project to quickly deploy a lightweight airflow for testing purposes.

My main issue here is that I can't find how to set the default password for the airflow container. The variable environment for setting the password does not seems to have any effect.

Comment: don't you need to encapsulate with brackets such as you did before ? `"airflow"`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, setting password has no effect!

As a workaround mounting customized [webserver_config.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/config_templates/default_webserver_config.py) will work. this will disable password login altogether.

Replace `# AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Viewer'` with `AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Admin'`

Then mount this file `your_local/webserver_config.py:/opt/airflow/webserver_config.py`

Now you can see Airflow Web UI without login as an Admin user

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but these commands allowed me to set my desired airflow username and password:

1. stop all containers and delete associated volumes:
   `docker compose down --volumes --rmi all`
2. delete all docker images:
   `docker rmi -f $(docker images -aq)`
3. clean-up leftover docker stuff:
   `docker system prune`
4. reset airflow's meta-database:
   `airflow db reset`

I'm sorry I can't say which of the 4 accomplished the trick, but I just "nuked" everything to start fresh. I hope someone more knowledgeable than me can answer which actually fixed the problem.

After this, when I re-ran `docker build` and `docker-compose up` with my desired `_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME` and `_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD`, I was able to log in to airflow's web UI with my specified combination.